# Shadow backup not available

Tags: windows-xp, windows-server-2003, storage, volume-shadow-copy, previous-versions

We are using **windows server 2003 R2**. In the server we have enabled the shadow backup for 4 drives& that can be accessible from any of client pcs. But in one **windows 7 home** pc we cannot access shadow backup. It is saying that "**There are no previous versions available**". What will be the issue?
Another issue is, in some client pcs (Most of the time it happens in XP home pcs), the Previous version **tab is not visible sometimes**. But at the same time it is available in other pcs. If we check after few minutes, it will visible properly. what may be the problem? Any solution for this error?

Answer (score 1):

XP Home and Win7 Home are not going to interop with Windows Server.

You need to get Pro version of your windows desktops. The time spent trying to meld Windows Home into a server environment is simply not worth the time-money trade off.